# dispatching API actions and loading stage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, dispatch, react-lifecycle-hooks

We know that if a Redux action triggers an **API call** to a server (whether in Redux middleware or Redux Thunk), it takes time to receive the answer from the server. During this **waiting phase**, the **UI** must somehow shows the user that some **loading** is being done (showing an Spinner for example). In React and React native, a famous trick to handle these common situations is a ***isLoading*** boolean flag in the Redux state and of course, a ***loading*** action being dispatched. This boolean will be toggled once the answer is ready to be shown, so that I can update the UI.

However, after applying this trick for years, what I've got is an application full of bugs and errors and a super dirty code with a lot of redundant code.

I have checked all the React **life cycle hooks** to check the order, in which the hooks are called **and** the process of Redux dispatching. It seems that Redux and React works totally **separately**. (I know that **getDerivedStateFromProps** is called once the store has been updated, but it does not solve my problem)

I need a better way to handle these common situations. I don't know if I need to make modification in Redux part of my application, or in the UI, or ...

Comment: I think a local isLoading state in component is much cleaner that the global isLoading state in redux.

Comment: What is the bug?How can we know what's your problem?

Comment: @Sina  A local state is not possible since the boolean flag has been used in different part of the application.

Comment: @DevinGong As the application and the code get bigger and more complicated, handling these situations will become a nightmare.